# RSACryptoServiceProvider.ToXmlString(); encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, byte

Im creating xml string from my RSA key:

```
var keyXmlString = rsaPrivKey.ToXmlString(true);
```

And now i would like to convert the string to bytes, something like this:

```
var xmlBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(keyXmlString);
```

The question is wehat would be the right encoding to use there wehn converting xml string to bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "right" encoding here - it depends, on who is your consumer. You need to use the encoding, your consumer expects.

I strongly suggest to do something like

```
var xmlBytes = Encoding.YOURENCODINGHERE.GetBytes("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"YOURENCODINGHERE\" ?>\n"+keyXmlString);
```

to make this more foolproof.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're consistent with the encoding and decoding it really doesn't matter which encoding you use.